# Local Notification is not clearing in iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, ibeacon

I'm using a Beacon device for testing. The scenario is as follows.
I'm throwing a local notifications when receiver enters the location which is based on latitude & longitude range which i have set manually. This works fine and i'm clearing this notification on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. When I enter to the next closest region i'm getting the notification and on clicking it I can able to present a view. But when i come out of the app the local notifications are not getting cleared. What may be the problem?

I'm using two different methods for two different regions.
1st one is

```
-(void) didEnterLocation:(SLMLocation*)location
{
// throwing a local notification
}
```

the above method's notification is getting cleared in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
```

the second method is as follows: this is for 2nd region

```
- (void) didEnterNewClosestRegion :(SLMBLERegion*) region
{
// throwing local notifications here & notifications are visible
}
```

Now in the second method only I can't able to clear the local notification. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is because **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method is only called one in app life time, there is a possibility that it is already running in background so the notifications will not be cleared. I would suggest you to move cancelling code to **applicationDidBecomeActive**.

cancelAllLocalNotifications, cancels the delivery of all scheduled local notifications, it doesn't clear already presented notifications from lock-screen or notification-center.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelAllLocalNotifications

Comment: i want to know why the notifications are not getting cleared when i use cancelAllLocalNotifications in applicationWillResignActive method. Do you have any idea of why this is not called?

Comment: Do you want to clear the scheduled notification? or the presented one? Can you be more specific and detailed.

Comment: NO. I don't use scheduled notifications at all. Just the presented one which i'm throwing.

Comment: Once notification presented, you can not clear it using code.

Comment: may I know the reason. Is there any ways to clear the notification?

Comment: Because Apple doesn't want applications to remove notifications from lock-screen or notification-center.

Comment: But then I was able to clear the local notification in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for region 1 :/

Comment: There must understand that cancelAllLocalNotifications has nothing to do with remove notification-items from lock-screen or notification-center. Its very clear in documentation "Cancels the delivery of all scheduled local notifications."

Answer (score 1):

try this may be help full ..

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

}
```

Thanks

Comment: i want to know why the notifications are not getting cleared when i use cancelAllLocalNotifications in applicationWillResignActive method. Do you have any idea of why this is not called?